# javascriptで変更した値がブラウザの戻るでおかしくなる。

Tags: javascript, jquery

AページとBページがあり
Aページで、ajaxで「その値」を1から2にしたとします。DBはその値は2です。

その後、Bページへ移動して、
**ブラウザの戻る、端末の戻る(特にANDROID)で戻るとAページの値が1になってしまいます**。

私がやりたいのは、とある値を「2」と表示させたいです。

かいけつさくとして
ブラウザの戻る、端末の戻るのイベントを取得して、その値をAページに持っていき、ゴニョゴニョしたいと思っています。

javascriptに詳しい方ぜひ教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

戻るボタンを押したときにブラウザーのキャッシュを使わずに、サーバーからデーターを読み直す様にするというのはいかがでしょうか？これだと`javascript`を使わずに、`header`に固定で

```
<meta equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta equiv="Cache-Control" content="private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0">
<meta equiv="Expires" content="Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT">
```

上記3行を追加しておくだけでいい様な気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。headタグに記載したいのですが、書けないのでbodyタグ内に記述してみましたが上手くいきませんでした。

Comment: `meta`タグは`head`内にしか書いても意味がありませんので、`body`に書いても上手く行かないと思います。`head`タグ内を編集できないのであれば、理由を質問に追記した方が適切な回答が得られやすいと思います

Comment: おはようございます。上司と相談してmetaでやることになりました。Yankaさんに、ありがとうみたいな評価したいんですがどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: お役に立てて幸いです。回答の左に△▽に挟まれた数字があると思います。この上下の▽が、この回答は役に立つ、立たないを示していて、クリックすると、この回答が役に立つと思った人数が増減し、多いほど役に立つ回答という判断基準になります。更に質問者はそのすぐ下に✔️がグレイで表示されているかとおもいます。このチェックマークをクリックすると、（複数貰った）回答のうち、どれが質問者にとって有効であったか？の意思表示になり、質問を検索したときに、有効な回答が付いた質問か？が解るので、後々同じ問題にぶつかった人の手助けになります。ので、1.質問を解決出来る回答が貰えたの✓をつける。2.上向き▲をクリックする。のいずれかまたは両方をしていただけると助かります。

Comment: こんにちは、アプリにmetaタグを追加するシステムがあったので入れてみましたが、1になってしまいます。キャッシュが反映されてしまいます。ちょっとmetaタグをいろいろといじってみて修正してみます。

Comment: `equiv`が`http-equiv`の省略なので、ちゃんと`http-equiv`と書かないと認識しないブラウザーもありそうですね